# Executing method from object, where method name is passed as string?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know if I have a function defined as:

```
void executeFunc(String funcName)
```

can I somehow execute MyObject.funcName();?

What I'm trying to do is have one Class that handles all calls to a server and they return XML data back, so I'd like to use the one AsyncTask to handle the 15 or so different types of calls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an do this using [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).